# How can we configure resources sharing among tenant?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 Carbon supports the following methods for sharing resources among tenants:

1. Private Jet mode
2. Separation at hardware level
3. Separation at JVM level
4. Native multitenancy

So how can we configure these resources among tenant?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot share data between Tenants in carbon platform. Tenants are considered as Isolated entities and there is no sharing of data.

Comment: Inside the official document of the API manager multi tenant below Resource sharing header they have mentioned about how the above following methods can be used for the sharing resources among tenant and they have provided the definition only but they have not given any details about how can we configure these sharing resource for tenant. Link of the document: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Multi+Tenant+Architecture

Comment: This resources reffer to hardware resources. Is your requirement this. I do some research and get back to you if this is you requirement.